# A JavaScript exception occurred when call javascript method in webview in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

I have a webview used to render a page with some questions and allow user to answer these questions and after that press a button in the native screen not in the webpage to get the result and submit it to server

this is a screen shot for my screen

[image]

and this is my javascript method

```
function helloWorld () {
                return "Hello World";
            }
```

it is now return static text

and this is the action of my button that should get data from webview via javascript

```
@IBAction func Submit_Action (){

        webView.evaluateJavaScript("helloWorld()") { (response, error) in
            print(error as Any)
            print(response as Any)
        }
}
```

I am using **"WKWebView"**

but the call of javascript method does not return my static value, but it give error :

```
 Optional(Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=1, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=ReferenceError: Can't find variable: helloWorld, WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=11, WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=<here_is_my_page_url>, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred})
```

can anyone help please ?

Comment: Could you post your HTML code?

I performed a small test with the most simpler configuration possible for a WKWebView and it worked fine.

Are you sure the page is loading in WKWebView?

Comment: I have the same problem :(